# Codename one:android native code not working on all android OS

Tags: codenameone

I have implemented android native code in codename of reading sim serial number using telephonyManager.getSimSerialNumber().Its working on android version 6.0 and above but on below version its not working .Getting runtime exception in below version.When we developed app using android studio and implemeted this functinality then its worked on all OS of android but when I implemented same android code in native using codename one then getting above issues .Its not working on all OS.
Can you please help me to solved this issues?

Comment: What's the exception error in the devices that are failing? Connect a cable and check

Answer (score 1):

There's a [library](https://github.com/Pmovil/Telephony) written by [Fabricio Cabeca](https://github.com/FabricioCabeca) a while ago for that. Search the Codename Extensions Library for `Telephony` (Right-click project -> Codename One -> CodenameOne Settings -> Extensions).  Use this cn1LIb.

If there's still an issue with Android below 6.0, add `android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` to your build hint.

Also, make sure you're not testing on Dual sim device, as this could problematic.

Comment: Yes I am testing it on Dual sim device because I want this functionality on all devices single sim as well as dual sim